# Oracle Managed Data Access Client can't work from IIS but work for local debug environment

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-4.8, oracle-manageddataaccess

I'm having trouble getting my Oracle connection to work with IIS. I've tried different methods, such as adjusting access permissions for authenticated users/IIS users to the Oracle client directory and adding Oracle_Home to my environment path. However, I'm still facing the error 'System.Data.OracleClient requires software version 8.1.7 or greater.' Just to note, my Oracle client installation includes the Basic Lite Package + ODBC Driver Package as per the link provided.

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html

I've tried different methods, such as adjusting access permissions for authenticated users/IIS users to the Oracle client directory and adding Oracle_Home to my environment path. However, I'm still facing the error 'System.Data.OracleClient requires software version 8.1.7 or greater.'

Comment: Try a clean build.  The clean build removes the intermediate obj file which forces all the code to rebuild.  The dependencies in the c# compile is not recognizing the library was updated so you have to force the project to get recompiled by either using Clean Build or deleting the bin folder (or obj folder).